# Double Integral Over an Elliptical Region

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need help with the following integral

$
\underset{R}{\int\int}e^{-a_1x^2-a_2xy-a_3x-a_4y-a_5y^2-a_6}dxdy
$

where $R=\{(x,y):b_1x^2+b_2xy+b_3y^2\leq c^2 \},\,\,\,\, a_i,b_i>0.$

I tried converting the region $R$ into a circular region and applying polar coordinates transformation but it doesnt help the function in the integrand since it involves an elliptic function.

Comment: I dont think there exists a closed form expression for this integral

Comment: @NN2 Any suggestions for approximate methods...other than numerical integration?

Comment: I recommend you this book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-01689-9. The author proposed several numerical methods for this kind of integral